# RFID get serial connection in a BluetoothSocket

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, rfcomm

I am trying to connect to a RFID reader device. I am able to connect to it by creating a BluetoothSocket and calling connect on it like below (many details omitted):

```
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");   
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID);
```

This much works as expected, and the connection with the device can be established.

My problem is, the device API is designed to work with a serial port. In order to use the API, I have to pass it a string that looks like this:

```
String uri = "eapi:///com1";
```

Android doesn't appear to open the serial port up to the world this way. On linux I would expect to be able to be able to connect with a string like:

```
String uri = "eapi:///dev/ttyS0";
```

Looking through the /dev directory on the handset shows nothing of the sort. Furthermore, the entries in /dev don't change when I establish the connection. This leads me to believe that Android doesn't create a serial device in /dev when it connects to a bluetooth device.

How can I access the com port that the BluetoothSocket is using to connect to the device? Is there a virtual device like com1 or /dev/ttyS0 on android?

Older versions of the API that used the class RfcommSocket had a getPort() and getFileDescriptor() methods that might help me out. The current bluetooth socket seems to hide away these details.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
It turns out that Android simply does not create a virtual device for the serial stream. Instead, I integrated my client code with the bluetoothsocket directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have the raw bluetooth socket and it is connected, why not just handle the data formatting/conversion manually in your code and send it to the other party without serial stream? A limited number of bluetooth profiles is supported by Android OS AFAIK.